# How many $5$-element subgroups does $S_7$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, permutations

> How many $5$-element subgroups are there in $S_7$, the group of permutations on $7$ elements?

Let $H$ be a $5$-element subgroup of $S_7$. We have $\mbox{ord}(H) = 5$ and $5\mid 7!$. 
But I don't have any idea how can I find 5-element subgroups.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

A subgroup of $S_7$ of order $5$ must be cyclic (all groups of prime order are cyclic), and therefore is generated by an element of order $5$.  The only elements of order $5$ in $S_7$ are $5$-cycles (why?), but each subgroup contains $4$ such cycles.  This reduces the problem to one of a combinatorial flavor.

Comment: Why each podgroup contains $4$ such cycles?

Comment: @Tomek: Every nonidentity element in a group of order $5$ has order $5$.  There are $4$ non-identity elements in a group of order $5$.

Comment: I don't understand. For example I can take $(1,2,3,4,5),(2,3,4,5,6),(3,4,5,6,7),(1,2,7,4,5),(2,3,4,5,6),(3,4,1,6,7)$ so I have $6$ non-identity elements...

Comment: @Tomek Those are not members of the same 5-element subgroup!  The point is that for each subgroup of order 5, there are exactly four elements of order 5 (the four non-identity members of that subgroup).

Comment: @Tomek: The elements you've listed do not form a subgroup.  Consider the subgroup with elements $e,(1,2,3,4,5),(1,3,5,2,4),(1,4,2,5,3),$ and $(1,5,4,3,2)$, and notice that there are four non-identity elements, and they all have order $5$.  Try listing out the elements of the subgroup generated by $(3,4,5,6,7)$.

Comment: Ok, so $<(1,2,3,4,5)>$ and $<(3,4,5,6,7>$ are subgroups. How can I find other subgroups? When is end?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some codes inspired by A. Konovalov's leading suggestions for doing the problem via GAP.

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(7);
gap> ccs:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G);;
gap> c5:=Filtered(ccs, c -> Size(Representative(c))=5);;
gap> Length(c5);
                                       1
gap> c5;
                      [ Group( [ (3,4,5,6,7) ] )^G ]
gap> Size(c5[1]);
                                      126
```

The conjugacy class of a 5-cycle contains 504 elements which is 4 times more:

```
gap> (3,4,5,6,7)^G;
gap> Size(last);
                                      504
gap> 504/126;
                                       4
```

Comment: + 1 $\ddot\smile!$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints** (completing and/or adding to some other comments or answers):

- Each group of order $\;5\;$ in $\;S_7\;$ is generated by a $\,5-$cycle (this is **false** in $\,S_n\;,\;\;n\ge10\;$ . Can you see why?)
- For each given subset of five elements in $\;\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\;$ we get a generator of a subgroup of order $\;5\;$ in $\;S_7\;$ and all of them yield different subgroup of order $\;5\;$ in $\;S_7\;$ .
- (kind of) *Another approach*: How many $\;5\;$ cycles are there in $\,S_7\;$ ? How many of them generate **the same** cyclic subgroup? For example

$$\langle (12345)\rangle =\langle(13524)\rangle=\langle(14253)\rangle =\ldots$$

Comment: This is a problem, that i don't know how many $5$ cycles there are, and which of them generete the same subgroup. Of course, we have  ${7 \choose 5} = 21 $ $5$-cycles. The problem is, that I don't know which of them are non-identity and which of them generate non-identity subgroup.

Comment: Well Tomek, one *has* to know something to attack this kind of problems in medium undergraduate level...